# Unable to locate Mix file on a subdomain Laravel instalattion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel on a subdomain. All Laravel files, except public folder, are in a folder in the same level of public_html folder.

The public folder files are inside subdomain folder, inside public_html folder.

I changed path of autoload.php and app.php, inside my_subdomain/index.php.

Everything is running fine. But I need to enable mix version and now Laravel show this error:

> Unable to locate Mix file: /js/app.js. Please check your
>   webpack.mix.js output paths and try again.

The mix-manifest.json file is inside the my_subdomain folder:

```
{
  "/js/app.js": "js/app.edb30a0318d87750bd69.js",
  "/css/app.css": "css/app.2e8af0500b8b83e4423e.css"
}
```

Comment: try without the leading forward slash

Comment: @delboy1978uk same error.

Answer (score 2):

Hey simply use the `asset()` function to use in

```html
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and with the mix development
this schoul help

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/326

Comment: The problem with `asset()` is that my app.js file was not updating, even cleaning browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Your index.php must content bind path for public directory

```
$app->bind('path.public', function () {
    return __DIR__;
});
```